# Open-Source projects, any good links?

Tags: iphone, open-source, projects

Anyone have any good open-source projects or links. Preferrably 3.0+ since 2.x is being fzed out.

Comment: There are zillions of them. What kind of projects are you looking for, and why (use/contribute/etc)?

Comment: Closing; this simply isn't a specific answerable question, unless you want the answer "yes, there are".

Comment: Yea, this question was asked a really long time ago. back in the 2.x days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this project

http://code.google.com/p/chibiorm/

It's an Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) framework for the iPhone. (it's like Hibernate/JPA for Java) This allows you to use objects to represent your database tables. That way you only deal with objects and not with SQL.